# Detail error message in .error() jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using .error() as the callback for .post(). Like :

```
 $.post("url", function(data){})
 .error(function(){
          alert("some error");
 });
```

I want to see the detailed error message if some error will occure. How can i see that ?

Comment: It is better to use `fail()` instead of deprecated `error()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
 $.post("url", function(data){})
 .error(function(event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError){
     console.log(event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError);
 });
```